# Asking to get user input in Python for a valid response using strings?

Tags: python

```
while True:
    try:
        horoscope= int(input("Enter what sign you are: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, please try again")
        continue
    else:
        break
if horoscope =='1':
    print("You are a Gemini!")
elif horoscope =='2':
    print("You are a Pisces!")
else:
    print("Mediate more and try again.")
```

I'm trying to write a very simple code that asks the user to enter their horoscope and have a message appear depending on what theirs is. So far, I have it set to only comparing user inputs to integers, but I would like the user to be able to enter the full name of their astrology sign instead of having signs assigned to certain integers and filtering through print statements that way. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Don't call `int` on the input line, and compare to `horoscope == "pisces"` instead of `horoscope == '2'`? There's really not much to it.

Comment: Wild guess; you already tried `horoscope= input("Enter what sign you are: ")` and when the user types in "pisces" it says `NameError: name 'pisces' is not defined`. If this is the case, you're using Python 2.7, which uses `raw_input` in place of `input`

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can compare strings like this:

```
if horoscope=="Pisces":
    #more code here
```

The two strings have to be perfectly equal for example: `Pisces` is not the same as `pisces`. You can read a little more about strings [here](http://thepythonguru.com/python-strings/)